# Group by in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tables for projects and members the main goal is one to many relationship.

I have many projects and many members, now I have to find how many members that are assigned in a particular project (I have many tables in addition to these I didn't mention here but you can see in my stored procedure)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PROJECT_EMPLOYSSSS]
(
  @Employee_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT E.Employee_ID, S.Project_Title, COUNT(E.First_Name) 
    FROM tbl_NEW_Employee AS E  
    INNER JOIN  tbl_NEW_Employee_Project AS K ON K.Employee_ID = E.Employee_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_NEW_Project AS S ON K.Project_ID = S.Project_ID 
    WHERE E.Is_Active=1 AND E.Employee_ID = @Employee_ID 
    Group BY E.First_Name
END
```

I am new to programming and stored procedures.

I am getting this error :

> Column 'tbl_NEW_Employee.Employee_ID' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Please help me to write this stored procedure using `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL, not SQL Server??

Comment: `GROUP BY E.Employee_ID,S.Project_Title` instead of `Group BY E.First_Name`.

Comment: [Naming Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx): "We recommend that you do not create any stored procedures using **sp_** as a prefix. SQL Server uses the **sp_** prefix to designate system stored procedures. The name you choose may conflict with some future system procedure."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is `SQL Server` and not `MySQL`.

You have to `GROUP BY` the columns on which you want to aggregate (i.e. output only one row per value):

```
SELECT E.Employee_ID,S.Project_Title,COUNT(E.First_Name) 
FROM tbl_NEW_Employee AS E  
INNER JOIN  tbl_NEW_Employee_Project AS K ON K.Employee_ID=E.Employee_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_NEW_Project AS S ON K.Project_ID=S.Project_ID 
WHERE E.Is_Active=1 AND E.Employee_ID=@Employee_ID 
Group BY E.Employee_ID,S.Project_Title
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `group by` clause in your sql query, then only those columns can be put in `select` column list which are in the `group by` column list.

In your above query you have only First_name in the `group by` column list, but you are trying to get `E.Employee_ID,S.Project_Title` in `select` column lists

if you want all the above fields in your select column then add them in your group by clause also.

```
SELECT E.Employee_ID,S.Project_Title,COUNT(E.First_Name) 
    FROM tbl_NEW_Employee AS E  
    INNER JOIN  tbl_NEW_Employee_Project AS K ON K.Employee_ID=E.Employee_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_NEW_Project AS S ON K.Project_ID=S.Project_ID 
    WHERE E.Is_Active=1 AND E.Employee_ID=@Employee_ID 
    Group BY E.Employee_ID,S.Project_Title
```

else remove them from your select list

```
SELECT COUNT(E.First_Name) ,E.First_Name
        FROM tbl_NEW_Employee AS E  
        INNER JOIN  tbl_NEW_Employee_Project AS K ON K.Employee_ID=E.Employee_ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_NEW_Project AS S ON K.Project_ID=S.Project_ID 
        WHERE E.Is_Active=1 AND E.Employee_ID=@Employee_ID 
        Group BY E.Employee_ID,S.Project_Title
```

Comment: `Group BY E.First_Name` with `COUNT(E.First_Name)` will work fine, but the count will be 1 because of the `First_Name` in the `GROUP BY` you have to remove it from the `GROUP BY`.